# How to bring "Match" word near Match Radio Buttons in ADF

Tags: radio-button, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am working on af:query for Search functionality in ADF. The code for same is given below

```
<af:query id="qu1" headerText="Search" disclosed="true"  styleClass="quButton" saveButtonText="Save"
          value="#{bindings.SearchByTitleAndAuthor.quDescriptor}" 
          model="#{bindings.SearchByTitleAndAuthor.quModel}" 
          queryListener="#{bindings.SearchByTitleAndAuthor.processQuery}"
          queryOperationListener="#{bindings.SearchByTitleAndAuthor.processQueryOperation}"/>
```

This provides me a Search region with various fields and 2 radio buttons named as "All" and "Any". 
My requirement is that the word "Match" should come before the radio button "All". I have checked on different links that the word "Match" comes by default when we use af:query. But, its not coming in my case. Please suggest some ways in which I can get it done.
My Jdeveloper version is "Studio Edition Version 11.1.1.7.0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your **view object**. Ensure that show match all/match any is checked as shown in the screenshot.

[image: View Criteria]

### ===EDIT===

OP was using custom skin. Causing the issue. After removing the custom skin, the issue went away as suggested.

Comment: Yep its exactly same as your ViewCriteria. My 2 radio buttons are coming as supposed to, but the word "Match" itself is not coming.

Comment: Are you using any custom skin. If not can you share the layout for the component.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, actually we are using custom skin. If I remove it, it is working fine as expected and "Match" word is appearing. Thanks for the suggestion.